# compare three different dates and set a new variable as the smallest one by using an update query and a SET CASE statement

Tags: sql

To whom it may concern,

I am trying to compare three different dates and set a new variable as the smallest one by using an update query and a SET CASE statement with SQL.

Please let me show you an example in order to have a better understanding of what I want to do.

---

As has been mentioned previously, there are three different dates ([date 1], [date 2] and [date 3]) and I want to set [final date] as the smallest one.

```
[date 1]       [date 2]        [date 3] [final date]
21/10/2015    22/10/2015  10/01/2016 21/10/2015
05/01/2016  01/01/2016 10/01/2016 01/01/2016
20/01/2016 15/01/2016 10/01/2016 10/01/2016
```

---

Here we can see the code I have written so far.

```
UPDATE [Gate Permission 2] 
    SET [Final Date] = CASE WHEN ([Date 1] < [Date 2] AND [Date 1] < [Date 3])
                            THEN [Final Date] = [Date 1]                                                                                                         
                            WHEN  [Date 2] < [Date 3])
                            THEN [Final Date] = [Date 2]
                            ELSE [Final Date] = [Date 3]
                       END
```

I am aware that there are similar questions in the forum but I have not been able to solve my problem.

Thank you very much in advance and I do apologize for the inconveniences.

Best regards,

Gonzalo

Comment: What is the issue with your query?  Also, tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: So what exactly is your problem? You can unpivot the dates and use the `min()` function.

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntax is:

```
UPDATE [Gate Permission 2]
    SET [Final Date] = (CASE WHEN ([Date 1] < [Date 2] AND [Date 1] < [Date 3])
                             THEN [Date 1]                                                                                                         
                             WHEN [Date 2] < [Date 3])
                             THEN [Date 2]
                             ELSE [Date 3]
                        END);
```

That is, there is no `[Final Date] =` in the `CASE` statement.

EDIT:

In MS Access, you would use `iif()`:

```
UPDATE [Gate Permission 2]
    SET [Final Date] = IIF([Date 1] < [Date 2] AND [Date 1] < [Date 3]),
                           [Date 1],
                           IIF([Date 2] < [Date 3]),
                               [Date 2],
                               [Date 3]
                              )
                          );
```

Answer (score 0):

Initially I tried to implement your solution but it did not work. Later on, I realized it's not possible to use the SET CASE statement when working with access (I thought it was not indispensable to mention it). 
Finally I used the Switch function and it works.